# Silverlight 3 - Binding To A DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

In WPF I would use an ObjectDataProvider. This dosn't seem to be available in Silverlight 3.

Is this just meant to be done via the C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    PersonContract personContract = new PersonContract();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        personContract.personList = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Person>();

        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            personContract.personList.Add(new Person() { FaxNo = "123456", IdNo = "12321354321", Name = "Pieter", RegNo = "www456gp", Surname = "Stoltz", TelNo = "00129394" });
        }


        mygrid.DataSource = personContract.personList;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        personContract.personList.Add(new Person() { FaxNo = "123456", IdNo = "12321354321", Name = "Santie", RegNo = "www456gp", Surname = "Van den Heever", TelNo = "00129394" });
    }
}

public class PersonContract
{
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Person> personList { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string TelNo { get; set; }
    public string FaxNo { get; set; }
    public string IdNo { get; set; }
    public string RegNo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the way to do it, but nice example to start me off - cheers